# Not getting 'Flows' option for Buttons in PowerApps Studio for Web

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, powerapps, power-automate

I am trying to create a simple PowerApps application using 'PowerApps Studio for Web', where I have already created a flow to create a new record in Dynamics 365. As per the tutorials I followed, I suppose to get a 'Flows' option under 'Action' tab. But, I am not getting it when I selected a custom button on Phone layout. Below is the image where I am having this issue.

Appreciate your help on this..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Flows option under the Action tab is not yet available in the Web version. Please use PowerApps Studio for Windows.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When can we expect this feature for Web version?